# rs.exe taking a long time to run

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

To keep a long story short, rs.exe is taking a long time to run on one of our servers, around 25 seconds, but only 2 seconds on another.  We shell out to rs.exe to trigger subscriptions but our use is irrelevant for this question (See next paragraph)

For testing the issue, and remove any subscription specific issues, we open command prompt and simply run rs.exe and let it error due to having no params supplied.  Even running it as basically as this it takes 25 seconds to error on one sever, and only 2 seconds to error on another.

Both servers are supposedly identical in terms of resources.

Does anyone know enough about the inner workings of rs.exe to suggest why this is happening?

Comment: Check to see if the Disable Recursion is the same for both servers.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771738(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Have asked our server guys to have a check.  Both server are indeed using different DNS servers so it's a possibility.